# Body field of an entry(channel) not being styled?

Tags: css, richtext

I hope this is the right place, not sure if its a css issue, or whether or not it has something to do with what EE is doing.

I have a news channel setup, with a main "body" field. This is a textarea. When the entry is outputted, it doe not take on the css styling. I do not have this problem anywhere else  within my templates, just these main body fields.

When I inspect it, all the HTML markup is there, however its just plain straight text.

Could EE be having any play in it, or am I missing something with regards to my css?

Answer (score 1):

If the field is a textarea type then it will be devoid of styling. Further to that there should be some simple options like auto br, none, can't recall the rest when you set the field up or edit it, these options are helpful dependant on how you want the field to behave.

if you wrap your tag in

tags in your template you'll at least get proper p styling, combine with setting your textarea field up with auto br you'll then get line breaks.

if you want more control, try making it a rte field or look at devot-ee for wysiwyg field types like wygwam or editor.

failing all that and I've misread your post can you throw up some screen shots of how you've set up your field.

Comment: Thats what I thought, it's set up as a plain text area, but i've tried it with Wyvern, EE RTE, but it still comes out minus formatting, despite it being targeted via my css. It's strange. Only think in my templates that I seem to have trouble styling!

Comment: Can u throw up some relevant code from ur template ?

Comment: Theres not really much to put up. Its simply the `{body}` tag.

Comment: Change the field to wyvern and when asked "update all entries" say yes.

Comment: Also, what EE version ?

Comment: On EE 2.5.2, and have tried that with Wyvern, updated all entries and still not formatting. Urgh!

Comment: Ignore me, Im a douche!
The reason I though it was happening was that none of my `<ul>`s were being styled. Turns out I had the margin overridden and it was being hid! Gues it was fine all along! Doh!